# Android Studio ClassNotFoundException after package rename

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I've been coding a game using libsgdx in android studio and decided to rename a package, now I get classnotfoundexception when I run it. I tried changing the name back, manually searching and replacing names of packages in files, nothing works.
Is there any way to force rebuild everything or reset the directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this helps: `File > Invalidate Caches`.

You could also try `Build > Rebuild Project` followed by `Build > Make`